# Can File system ACL's help me keep php scripts away from other users

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

Many of my php scripts have got 644 permission and I would prefer that to be set to 400 so that  other users on the system can't access them unless called by webserver. Is it possible to set any file system acl to achieve this without  fiddling with apache/php/suphp?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about setting file permissions in Linux:

```
chmod 400 filename
```

Comment: Jared, chmodding the file might block the script from working. I want to restrict the other users on the server from accessing the files without making changes to file permissions.. By default I have it set to 644 and that is how shared servers like it.

Comment: Ah ok... you may want to edit your question to say "so that other users on the system" rather than "others", since it's a bit misleading as it is. I'll have to give this one some thought.

Answer (score 0):

ACL's is, what you are looking for.
by using ACL's you can set very granular restrictive access rules and also keep access for service users, like wwwrun and so on.
It is important, that your filesystem supports ACL's.

Use the [getfacl](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugetfacl.htm) and [setfacl](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm) commands
Here is an small tutorial: http://www.gnutoolbox.com/acls-setfacl/
But, btw: root will get access in every case.